# How to change "echo" to some textarea or label on PHP Class

Tags: php, class, encryption, textarea, echo

I'm here to explain my website and show the "bug" or "error" that appears to my web.

Some days ago I did a page, the topic is encrypt and decrypt with AES.

Here is a screenshot:

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP9XV.jpg)

but when I crypt or decrypt something very very LONG..
look that:

[Second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnXoP.png)

As you can see, the text goes on and on .. the idea I have is that when I press Encrypt / Decrypt, create a label and on that label, print the result.
If it is in a label or a textarea, the text would not follow to the right, it would go down.

Here is the php code when you click on "Encrypt" / "Decrypt":

```
<?php

if ($_POST['direction2'])
{

include 'AES.php';
$imputText = $_POST['imputText'];
$imputKey = $_POST['imputKey'];
$blockSize = $_POST['blockSize'];
$aes = new AES($imputText, $imputKey, $blockSize);

$enc = $aes->encrypt();
$aes->setData($enc);
$dec=$aes->decrypt();
echo "Encriptado: ".$enc."<br/>";
echo "Original: ".$dec."<br/>";
}
else if($_POST['direction1'])
{

include 'AES.php';
$imputText = $_POST['imputText'];
$imputKey = $_POST['imputKey'];
$blockSize = $_POST['blockSize'];
$aes = new AES($imputText, $imputKey, $blockSize);

$enc = $aes->encrypt();
$aes->setData($enc);
$dec=$aes->decrypt();
echo "Original: ".$dec."<br/>";

$enc = $aes->decrypt();
$aes->setData($enc);
$dec=$aes->decrypt();
echo "Desencriptado: ".$dec."<br/>";

}
?>
```

As you can see, I print the result with an "echo".

Thanks to everyone!
Hope u can help me.

Comment: you could just add something like this to your element 

.breakwords{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

Comment: @Sebastian If I understood you correctly, you're asking how to wrap the single line of ciphertext into multiple lines of ciphertext, right?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, you are right

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnXoP.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a long string not using space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195804/split-a-long-string-not-using-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `css` class with `word-wrap: break-word`, i.e.:

```css
.some_class {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
Correct:
<p class="some_class">vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv<p>

Incorrect:  
<p>vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv<p>
```

Comment: I know this, but i try to use the php code, when generate a text by "echo.." when generate this text, it appears so long..  you post one example about html, thanks by the way but im looking something to use on php

Comment: despite what you output in `php`, if the `html` doesn't have a `css` element using  `word-wrap: break-word;`, your text won't be displayed as you want.

Comment: My index, it is .php because im using mcrypt, so basically I dont have html, just php, and the classes are php too